# Why is copying a Uint8Array to a Uint8ClampedArray slower than copying a Uint8Array to a new Uint8Array?

Tags: javascript, arraybuffer, typed-arrays

It appears that copying a `Uint8Array` into a `Uint8ClampedArray` is much slower than cloning the `Uint8Array` and using its underlying `ArrayBuffer`:

```js
const foo = new Uint8Array(0x10000000); // 256MiB
console.time('Copy into Uint8ClampedArray');
const bar = new Uint8ClampedArray(foo);
console.timeEnd('Copy into Uint8ClampedArray');
```

The code above clocks at ~160ms on my machine (Chrome v96, MacBook Pro).

```js
const foo = new Uint8Array(0x10000000); // 256MiB
console.time('Clone, then use ArrayBuffer');
const bar = new Uint8ClampedArray(new Uint8Array(foo).buffer);
console.timeEnd('Clone, then use ArrayBuffer');
```

The code above clocks at ~70ms on my machine.

Firefox gives similar stats (140ms vs 60ms), while Safari shows more extreme differences (550ms vs 30ms).

Comment: I can confirm it's a lot faster on Firefox at least. Note you don't need to copy to new Uint8Array, just access the original buffer directly. https://jsfiddle.net/sdvu3kj6/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing those time differences in browser or in NodeJs

```
foo = new Uint8Array(256 * 1024**2); // 256MiB
console.time(label = 'Copy into Uint8ClampedArray');
bar = new Uint8ClampedArray(foo);
console.timeEnd(label);

foo = new Uint8Array(256 * 1024**2); // 256MiB
console.time(label = 'Clone, then use ArrayBuffer');
bar = new Uint8ClampedArray(new Uint8Array(foo).buffer);
console.timeEnd(label);
```

```
$ node -v && node test.js
v17.2.0
Copy into Uint8ClampedArray: 174.049ms
Clone, then use ArrayBuffer: 193.819ms

$ node -v && node test.js
v17.2.0
Copy into Uint8ClampedArray: 170.152ms
Clone, then use ArrayBuffer: 192.41ms

$ node -v && node test.js
v17.2.0
Copy into Uint8ClampedArray: 168.555ms
Clone, then use ArrayBuffer: 209.525ms
```

Comment: I tested on Node 16 (V8 9.4), and 17 (V8 9.6) and can confirm that Node 17 optimizes Uint8Array → Uint8ClampedArray copying much better than the previous versions. Perhaps something happened between V8 9.4 and 9.6?

Oddly enough, I'm still seeing significant speed differences in Chrome v96, despite it being powered by V8 9.6. So the optimization might be unrelated to V8 itself.

What OS and CPU are you on?